# Group by Error when using DATE() or Trun()

Tags: sql, group-by, amazon-redshift

I am trying to get the count of appointments on a given day, on a given ServiceResource. Each of these values are stored in different tables requiring me to use joins. The code I am using is below:

```
select
trunc(s.actualstarttime) "Delivery Date",
s2.name "Van Name", 
count(a.serviceid) "Stops"
from
assignedresource a
join serviceappointment s on s.id = a.serviceid
inner join serviceresource s2 on s2.id = a.serviceid
where
s.status = 'Completed'  and
s.actualstarttime > '2021-12-20 00:00:00' and s.actualstarttime < '2021-12-23 23:00:00'
group by 1, 2
order by
actualstarttime desc;
```

My expected output should give me a table like this:

2021-12-23 | Van A  | 3

2021-12-23 | Van B  | 4

2021-12-22 | Van A  | 5

But I keep getting this error :
*SQL Error [500310] [42803]: Amazon Invalid operation: column "s.actualstarttime" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function;*

I have tried using
`group by trunc(s.actualstarttime), s2.name` as well. Can someone help me figure out why or how can I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to the `ORDER BY` expression.

The concept involved is called "functional dependence", where expressions related to each group (select list expressions, order by expressions, etc) must be functionally dependent on the `GROUP BY` terms.  So we can select the `GROUP BY` terms directly or any aggregate/group function, like `MAX(s.actualstarttime)`, etc.

Since each result row (group) is based on "Delivery Date", you should be able to do something like this:

[Fiddle based on postgresql 14](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=17afecfa88d3ceaf6f91435877908fa3)

```sql
select s.actualstarttime::date "Delivery Date"
     , s2.name "Van Name"
     , count(a.serviceid) "Stops"
  from assignedresource a
  join serviceappointment s  on s.id  = a.serviceid
  join serviceresource    s2 on s2.id = a.serviceid
 where s.status = 'Completed'
   and s.actualstarttime > '2021-12-20 00:00:00'
   and s.actualstarttime < '2021-12-23 23:00:00'
 group by 1, 2
 order by s.actualstarttime::date desc
;
```

The result:

| Delivery Date | Van Name | Stops |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-23 | Van A | 3 |
| 2021-12-23 | Van B | 4 |
| 2021-12-22 | Van A | 5 |